# AWS Lambda | Runtime import module error: cannot import name 'x509' from 'cryptography'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cryptography

I am trying to deploy the following function in Python on AWS Lambda:

```
import json
import boto3
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    connect_str = os.getenv('CONNECT_STR')
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    records = event["Records"]
    
    print("Received records from s3 to update" + str(len(records)))
    
    for record in records:
        key = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
        bucket_name = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        print("Processing object with key:" + str(key))
        file = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
        itr = file["Body"].iter_chunks()
        azure_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=bucket_name)
        azure_container_client.upload_blob(name=key, data=itr)
        print("Object " + key + " transferred to azure successfully")
```

I download all the dependency by the following code on the terminal (Windows Power Shell):
`pip3 install target='Target Directory' azure-storage-blob`

Then, I zipped the target directory including`lambda_function.py`, then deployed to the AWS Lambda.

However, I received the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'x509' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "ca956e23-0d79-4897-8cfd-a0d74bca0098",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

The Runtime: Python 3.9
The Architecture: x86_64

I can successfully run `from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import x509` without any problem on my local computer.

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: well, you are missing a dependency. Did you use virtual env? I always use virtual env when developing lambda locally, to make sure I don't have conflict with existing dependency on my system and to work in a isolated environment.

Comment: I haven't used virtual environment. But, when I download `azure-storage-blob`, it also downloads all the dependencies it requires, right? Also, the target directory includes `cryptography`. So, is it really a dependency problem? @brushtakopo

Comment: I suggest you follow this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-update-venv
use virtual env and run the lambda locally to see if you are not missing anything.

Comment: Hi @AlexisFacques, what do you mean by how I build the lambda function? I built it via AWS Lambda and I am trying to deploy it via .zip upload. Please let me know if I could provide you more details.

Comment: Hi @brushtakopo again, I followed the link you've provided. But, I still received the same error. What could be the reasons?

Comment: If you run the lambda locally (within virtual env), does it through the same error?

Comment: @brushtakopo, No, there was no mistake when I run the script within the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by creating my package with this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t . --implementation cp --python-version 3.12 --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade
```

instead of this which I used before:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
```

My `requirements.txt` is one line:

```
cryptography==42.0.5
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to follow *Creating .zip deployment packages with native libraries* section in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) to build distribution for required platform (Linux for AWS Lambda):

```
pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=package--implementation cp --python 3.10 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade azure-storage-blob
```

Then you can add `lambda_function.py` into mentioned target folder, zip it and deploy to AWS Lambda.